# Should / Can we answer overly broad questions with overly broad answers?

Tags: discussion

When a wild ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical question appear, other than voting to close it, should / can we provide an equally broad answer (when reasonably possible)?

*inb4: this is a broad question*

Comment: Reason for the down vote?

Comment: [Votes are different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences). People disagree that you should answer broad questions.

Comment: @Manishearth, next time I'll post it the other way around then: "Shouldn't we answer [...]".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, do not provide an answer to questions that you think should be closed. In the case of broad questions, flag to close or vote to close as Not A Real Question, leave a comment telling the OP that the question is too broad (and how to make it less broad), and move on.

Answer (score -2):

Questions that aren't specific enough to have one correct answer are by definition off topic.  If a question is broad enough to cover a large topic, it should be broken into smaller questions, as those aren't the type of questions that StackOverflow does well with.

---

**In response to your edit:**

No, ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical questions should be closed.

Comment: Too broad questions are still on-topic; they just needs to be closed as "not a real question." I can ask a question about Xcode on Stack Overflow; if it is too broad, it is closed, even if it is not off-topic.